# How to programmatically update and delete LDAP users from SQL?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, active-directory

So i'm looking to grab some ldap values, and insert them into a database with encryption.  I've got the insert working but i need to check if the user is still part of the group and if not remove them from the DB, and if there was a new user added it inserts them instead of inserting existing users.  Can you give me some direction on best practices for this? I'd prefer not to truncate the table and re-insert all.

```
        try
        {
            /* Connection to Active Directory */
            DirectoryEntry deBase = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + txtLDAP.Text + ":" + txtLDapPort.Text + "/" + txtBadeDN.Text, txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

            /* Directory Search*/
            DirectorySearcher dsLookForGrp = new DirectorySearcher(deBase);
            dsLookForGrp.Filter = String.Format("(cn={0})", txtGroup.Text);
            dsLookForGrp.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
            dsLookForGrp.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
            SearchResult srcGrp = dsLookForGrp.FindOne();

            /* Directory Search
             */
            DirectorySearcher dsLookForUsers = new DirectorySearcher(deBase);
            dsLookForUsers.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectCategory=person)(memberOf={0}))", srcGrp.Properties["distinguishedName"][0]);
            dsLookForUsers.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
            dsLookForUsers.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectSid");
            dsLookForUsers.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
            SearchResultCollection srcLstUsers = dsLookForUsers.FindAll();

            StringBuilder sbUsers = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (SearchResult sruser in srcLstUsers)
            {
                SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier((byte[])sruser.Properties["objectSid"][0], 0);
                string ConnString = "ConnectionString Removed";
                string SqlString = "spInsertADAuthorization";
                using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
                {
                    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("AD_Account", SpartaCrypto.SpartaEncryptAES(sruser.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString(), "thisisasharedsecret"));
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("AD_SID", SpartaCrypto.SpartaEncryptAES(sid.ToString(), "thisisasharedsecret"));
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("AD_EmailAddress", "user@host.com");
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateImported", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Active", 1);
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
                lblResults.Text = srcLstUsers.Count + " Users granted access.";
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message.Contains("Logon failure"))
            {
                lblResults.Text = "Logon Failure.  Check your username or password.";
            }

            if (ex.Message.Contains("The server is not operational"))
            {
                lblResults.Text = "LDAP Error.  Check your hostname or port.";
            }
            if (ex.Message.Contains("Object reference not set to an instance of an object"))
            {
                lblResults.Text = "LDAP Error.  Check your hostname, port, or group name and try again.";
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

You can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
// and with the first name (GivenName) of "Bruce"
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
qbeUser.GivenName = "Bruce";

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
}
```

For working with a single principal, the programming interface is also much nicer:

```
// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

if(user != null)
{
   // do something here... you can access most of the commonly used properties easily
   user.GivenName = "....";
   user.Surname = "......";
   user.SamAccountName = ".....";
}

// find the group in question
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupNameHere");

// if found....
if (group != null)
{
   // iterate over members
   foreach (Principal p in group.GetMembers())
   {
      Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.StructuralObjectClass, p.DisplayName);
      // do whatever you need to do to those members
   }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really **much easier** to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: i'll look into that, thanks.  But the idea ow what im trying to get from this is how to manage inserting users that just joined the group and not re-inserting the users that we already have in the DB.  Also removing users that are in the DB but that are no longer part of the group.